# How to ignore a csv delimiter on specific scenarios in python?

Tags: python, postgresql, csv, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert data in DB using a CSV file.

```
import psycopg2 #import the postgres library
#connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='1.11.11.111',
                   dbname='postgres',
                   user='postgres',
                   password='myPassword',
                   port='1234')  
#create a cursor object 
#cursor object is used to interact with the database
cur = conn.cursor()
#open the csv file using python standard file I/O
#copy file into the table just created 
with open("C:/Users/Harshal/Desktop/tar.csv", 'r') as f:
next(f) 
cur.copy_from(f, 'geotargets_india',sep=',')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
f.close()
```

My table is as follows:

```
create table public.geotargets_india(
Criteria_ID integer not null,
Name character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
Canonical_Name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
Parent_ID NUMERIC(10,2),
Country_Code character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
Target_Type character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
Status character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL
)
```

my CSV looks like:

[image: CSVIMG]

the error I get is:
[image: Err]
If one look closely to my csv rows for example: `1007740,Hyderabad,"Hyderabad,Telangana,India",9061642.0,IN,City,Active` . Here, `Canonical_Name` has "," separated string which is causing the error and assuming there are more columns in CSV than the table. How to fix this?
Note: I'm assuming the error is due to this only.
[CSV Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19VmcLyo75H8rFZyDCSS6RrGqWaoX1Sko/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Probably you need https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foo.csv:

```
It is header which will be ignored------------------------------------
1007740,Hyderabad,"Hyderabad,Telangana,India",9061642.0,IN,City,Active
```

Python:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect('')
cur = conn.cursor()
f = open('foo.csv', 'r')
cur.copy_expert("""copy geotargets_india from stdin with (format csv, header, delimiter ',', quote '"')""", f)
conn.commit()
```

psql:

```
table geotargets_india;
┌─────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┬────────┐
│ criteria_id │   name    │      canonical_name       │ parent_id  │ country_code │ target_type │ status │
├─────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┼────────┤
│     1007740 │ Hyderabad │ Hyderabad,Telangana,India │ 9061642.00 │ IN           │ City        │ Active │
└─────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: I have one follow-up question: instead of reading CSV as a file how do we use a data frame instead of picking a saved file? I'm manipulating the original CSV using pandas.

Comment: @eras'q Sorry I am not Python/Pandas specialist, just got some knowledge from here and there.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read and parse the CSV file yourself in Python and then use `INSERT` statements to load the data into the DB.

```py
import csv
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host='1.11.11.111',
    dbname='postgres',
    user='postgres',
    password='myPassword',
    port='1234'
)  
cur = conn.cursor()

with open("tar.csv") as fd:
    rdr = csv.DictReader(fd)
    cur.executemany("""
        INSERT INTO geotargets_india
        VALUES (%(Criteria_ID)s, %(Name)s, %(Canonical_Name)s, %(Parent_ID)s, %(Country_Code)s, %(Target_Type)s, %(Status)s);
        """,
        rdr
    )

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

A few comments on the above. The [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) class will return dictionaries of your CSV. The returned DictReader object, `rdr`, is iterable, so it can be used directly in psycopg2's [cursor.executemany](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) function, which is probably more efficient that iterating through the csv DictReader object yourself.

Comment: I'll have to install CSV before importing it right? I tried pip install csv and getting error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement csv (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for csv`.

Comment: No, `csv` is part of the Python standard library so you do not have to install it. Check out its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thanks, but still getting error `InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
LINE 3:         VALUES ('2356', 'India', 'India', '', 'IN', 'Country...
`   from line `---> 22     cur.executemany("""
`

Comment: Looks like the Parent_ID in that line (the fourth value) is blank or missing. With psycopg2, a blank string (`''`) is incompatible with a numeric type. If you expect a NULL value in this case, then you need to convert the blank strings to `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You are right about the problem being in Canonical_Name. I successfully imported line `1007740,Hyderabad,"Hyderabad",9061642.0,IN,City,Active` in table with your structure.

Unfortunately, the copy_from method does not support the csv separator parameter. here is the documentation https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from

So you can reformat the csv file with a tab delimiter and then use copy_from

```
import csv
import psycopg2 #import the postgres library
#connect to the database
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='1.11.11.111',
                   dbname='postgres',
                   user='postgres',
                   password='myPassword',
                   port='1234')
#create a cursor object
#cursor object is used to interact with the database
cur = conn.cursor()
#open the csv file using python standard file I/O
#copy file into the table just created

with open("C:/Users/Harshal/Desktop/tar.csv", 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    with open("C:/Users/Harshal/Desktop/tar.tsv", 'w') as tsv:
        writer = csv.writer(tsv, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerows(reader)

with open("C:/Users/Harshal/Desktop/tar.tsv", 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    cur.copy_from(f, 'geotargets_india',sep='\t')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    f.close()
```

Comment: Getting error `InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY geotargets_india, line 1, column criteria_id: ""
` at line  `    cur.copy_from(f, 'geotargets_india',sep='\t')
`